# Rails Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I wanted to take this method:

```
self.spend_on_scholarships_for_african_people = training_programs.scholarships.joins(:participants).where('participants.race' => AFRICAN_RACES).sum('participants.spend')
```

and now want break it into different genders. We capture gender within the participants table. so i tried using active records [array conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) within the query to do so like this:

```
self.bursary_spend_on_potential_female_employees = training_programs.scholarships.joins(:participants).where('participants.race = ? AND participants.gender = ?', AFRICAN_RACES, 'Female').sum('participants.spend')
self.bursary_spend_on_potential_male_employees = training_programs.scholarships.joins(:participants).where('participants.race = ? AND participants.gender = ?', AFRICAN_RACES, 'Male').sum('participants.spend')
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT SUM(participants.spend) AS sum_id FROM `training_programs` INNER JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`training_program_id` = `training_programs`.`id` WHERE `training_programs`.`skills_development_id` IS NULL AND `training_programs`.`skills_development_type` = 'SkillsDevelopment' AND `training_programs`.`scholarship` = 1 AND (participants.race = 'African','Coloured','Indian' AND participants.gender = 'Female'):
```

I have cut up my query and i can't seem to find what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
participants.race = 'African','Coloured','Indian'
```

should be

```
participants.race IN ('African','Coloured','Indian')
```

To get that `SQL` result, change the way you build your query to something like:

```
participants.race IN (?)
```

Comment: zwippie you legend you!! it wasnt looking at it like an array. i was confused since it was working fine in the first instance. thank you so much!